# RxJava2 zip two Flowables into one

Tags: java, rx-java2, reactivex

I am struggling to find any RxJava2 examples of zipping two Flowables into one.

I am trying to modify [this test](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/jmh/java/io/reactivex/parallel/ParallelPerf.java) to include something along the lines of

```
    Integer[] ints = new Integer[count];
    Integer[] moreints = new Integer[count];
    Arrays.fill(ints, 777);
    Arrays.fill(moreints, 777);

    Flowable<Integer> source = Flowable.fromArray(ints);
    Flowable<Integer> anothersource = Flowable.fromArray(moreints);

    Flowable<Integer> zippedsources = Flowable.zip(source, anothersource,
            new BiFunction<Flowable<Integer>, Flowable<Integer>, Flowable<Integer>>() {

                @Override
                public void apply(Flowable<Integer> arg0, Flowable<Integer> arg1) throws Exception {
                    return arg0.blockingFirst() + arg1.blockingLast();
                }

    }).runOn(Schedulers.computation()).map(this).sequential();
```

Edit: I am trying to take an Integer from source and anothersource and add them up but it seems fundamentally different from the RxJava1 way of doing that ... I have tried a bunch of variations returning Integer, Publisher, Flowable and void but keep getting and error in Eclipse on the zip operator itself.

I am unable to figure out what goes where in `.zip(Iterable<? extends Publisher<? extends T>>, Function<? super Object[], ? extends R>).`

Comment: what results are you expecting and what results do you have for now?

Comment: Try `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>` and adjust the `apply` method's types as well. The zipping function doesn't get the source `Flowable`s but one value of each per invocation.

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd - this was exactly my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you only need to zip two flowables, you could use `Flowable.zipWith` Operator.

The way it is used is as following:

```
source.zipWith(anotherSource, new BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override public Integer apply(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a + b;
    } 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for `BiFunction`.